# grid-column: span creates extra columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am quite new to CSS Grid. I have a simple gallery where the column of the items is unknown.

I have the following CSS for the parent:

```
.gallery {    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr) );
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-gap: 1px;
}
```

And the items in the gallery can have classes which take multiple columns, for example:

```
.grid-col-2 {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

But I am having a problem. When the browser is resized (or in mobile) if there is space for only one column (width below 600px in my case), the `grid-column` breaks the layout, and instead of having one column only, there are 2, and the second column is not sized properly.

Now the first thing that came in my mind is to create a media rule saying if the width is below 600px, instead use `grid-column: 1 / -1`. But  this bring me on another problem (with no solution afaik), the gallery will not necessarily be 100% the width of the window, and there are no media rules that are based on the width of the parent.

Here is an image showing what is happening:

[image]

And here is a fiddle of the same: https://jsfiddle.net/pynd13bv/

Is there a way to tell the Grid not to create extra columns because of `grid-column`, but instead to just take one full row without breaking the layout?

Comment: Are you trying to get, as an example, the `image0` and `image1` divs to be the same size after 600px?  Or trying to get them all to stack?

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the column `grid-column` creates, so `.grid-col-2` should take one full row if there is no space for 2, and not create an extra one.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer, as I missed the `not full width of body` comment. That being said, CSS won't know that it doesn't have space because the grid is defined as two columns (which you already appear to know). Can you give an example of the markup of the entire body? As simple as possible. Is the gallery going to be next to another element on smaller screens? You could give a class to the gallery container, using JS, if it reaches a specific size on window resize.

Comment: I guess it's impossible or it would require a lot of hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to do this with [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). As of Feb 2023, the browser support is just [above 80%](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries).

```js
function updateInnerWidth() {
  document.getElementById('innerWidth').textContent = "Inner Width: " + window.innerWidth;
}

updateInnerWidth();
window.onresize = updateInnerWidth;
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.gallery div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery div.grid-col-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: green;
}

.gallery div.grid-col-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
  background-color: blue;
}

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@container (max-width: 600px) {
  .gallery div.grid-col-3 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}

@container (max-width: 400px) {
  .gallery div.grid-col-2 {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div>Image 0</div>
  <div>Image 1</div>
  <div class="grid-col-2">Image 2</div>
  <div class="grid-col-2">Image 3</div>
  <div>Image 4</div>
  <div>Image 5</div>
  <div class="grid-col-3"> Image 6</div>
  <div>Image 7</div>
</div>

<p style="margin-top: 100px;" id="innerWidth"></p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vg0spb5/)